# Babel generated code causes error exports is undefined

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

When this code (generated from babel) runs I get an error `exports is undefined`

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are most likely not executing the code in an environment that supports CommonJS modules. You could use a bundler, such as [Browserify](http://browserify.org) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io)
to bundle your modules into something that can be run in different environments.

Or you could choose a different [module transformer](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/).

---

With webpack

Run `npm install -g webpack; npm install -D babel-loader`. Then with this  webpack configuration:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: "./path/to/entry/module.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
      ]
    }
};
```

running the `webpack` command will convert all `*.js` files reachable via the entry file with babel and bundle them together into `bundle.js`.

Comment: oh i thought I could just run the babel output in the browser

Comment: so I just download webpack in npm and use that script?

Comment: I recommend to read the webpack documentation :) Also see https://babeljs.io/docs/using-babel/#webpack in that case.

Comment: I just want to create a script that will bundle it for a cdn that someone will use. They wont have webpack.

Comment: I understand. Webpack bundles all modules and produces a single file.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps me https://github.com/babel/babel-loader + the docs are a bit confusing to my case

Comment: Well, I would start with http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/ .

Answer (score 3):

I read an article about how ES6 import and export are only supposed to work in browser with "statically analyzable files" and Babel removed import and export support in the browser because of this. Something to do with async or possibly security?

If you want to skip the server-side bundling for dev purposes, you can put

`window.MyModule = MyModule` at the bottom, then import

`var MyModule = window.MyModule` at the top of your next file